# node.js, cluster mode, log aggregation and logrotate

Tags: node.js, fork, logrotate

Node has a "cluster" module, using which one can create a parent process that forks worker children. The worker children all listen on the same socket, thus load balancing between them (and thus between CPU's) happens at the kernel.

Such a process would also have to monitor for children dying and fork new ones instead, presumably with some exponential backoff. It would also be very nice if such a process aggregated all the childrens' stdout to one file, their stderr to another, and supported SIGHUP to reopen these files (for logrotate).

If I understand correctly, pm2 can do that. Other than pm2, though -- is there any battle-proven module/script/package to do that, or do I have to write my own?

What are companies who have taken node to production do?

Comment: And the `cluster` module is _not_ stable, it is experimental. Use at your own risk in production. Furthermore, this question appears to be off topic because this question does not appear to be about programming

Comment: @RPM: I considered first posting in "Unix & Linux", but then realized that all articles and references I find to this are actually programming. People spin up their own such master modules and post demo code all the time. As for experimental: I agree, but again have seen many articles that advocate using it. What are the alternatives for running server node apps on a multi-core machine?

Answer (score 0):

Walmart (at least initially) decided to not use clustering, and instead run each machine with a single node process.  Here's a gist on their setup: https://gist.github.com/hueniverse/7686452

PM2 seems like a popular choice for those who do want to advantage of spreading their node app across multiple CPUs.

As far as log aggregation and log rotation, I'd imagine the basic unix `logrotate` gets a lot of use.

Comment: on ec2, for example, single-core comes at a price of low network bandwidth and low memory. So I might not have a "choice" and get a server with multi-core. If the CPU is there it's a shame not to use it. As for logrotate: of course, I meant who writes the code to handle SIGHUP -- is it part of the app's code? That's mixing business logic and ops concerns.

Comment: Honestly I've had success in running with `upstart`, and having it execute node directly to start the app (but have it run the process as a non-root user).  I can understand the desire to run on all processes available, which is why pm2 is used a lot, it's just interesting to see a company such as Walmart who gets tons of traffic perform fine with single process VMs.  Might make deployment a bit less complicated.

Comment: I think a lot of this also depends on what your app will be doing, since most of the time these Node apps aren't doing much but waiting on network/databases/file IO/etc.  And the async nature really helps with this, which can reduce the need to scale up (on the Node app).